# Dynamic layout for WKInterfacePicker - Swift - Watch App

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I am creating a watch app and I have a problem with my pickers.

I want have some pickers side by side horizontal like this :

```
<!--Page1-->
        <scene sceneID="db6-OT-aHK">
            <objects>
                <controller identifier="Page1" id="U48-q0-PUn" customClass="Page1" customModule="swiftTest_WatchKit_Extension">
                    <items>
                        <group width="1" alignment="center" verticalAlignment="center" id="tfC-gp-OjA">
                            <items>
                                <picker width="0.33000000000000002" height="100" alignment="center" verticalAlignment="center" id="5k4-Oj-Imh"/>
                                <picker width="0.33000000000000002" height="100" alignment="center" verticalAlignment="center" id="CWU-iM-QA5"/>
                                <picker width="0.33000000000000002" height="100" alignment="center" verticalAlignment="center" id="7EB-A5-pKO"/>
                            </items>
                        </group>
                        <group width="1" alignment="left" verticalAlignment="bottom" id="nmP-yl-udb">
                            <items>
                                <button width="1" alignment="left" title="Button" id="rSf-z8-JuU"/>
                            </items>
                        </group>
                    </items>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="goButton" destination="rSf-z8-JuU" id="FMh-MS-VME"/>
                        <outlet property="picker1" destination="5k4-Oj-Imh" id="Y6q-wM-MPf"/>
                        <outlet property="picker2" destination="CWU-iM-QA5" id="X2S-hS-XfV"/>
                        <outlet property="picker3" destination="7EB-A5-pKO" id="V3z-ek-cGw"/>
                    </connections>
                </controller>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="463" y="61"/>
        </scene>
```

But, my WKPickerItem vary in size. With my method which fix the size of each picker, I have big white space for short WKPickerItem and some others WKPickerItem are cut because they are too long..

Is it possible to have variable size for these pickers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can adapt size of picker dynamically with setWidth/Height but there is not possibilities to adapt automatically the size of pickers.

I think that pickers are not thought to do this in the watch